# Bandwidth Monitoring using c++ program

Tags: c++

I am developing a small application that requires a module that would check whether there is bandwidth or not.Basically the module should trigger an event when the bandwidth goes down. Can this be achieved using c++ program

Comment: Are you talking about internet or network access? Which operating system?

Comment: it's completely not portable if you'd like to do this as independent application (independent on that that actually receives data). so you need to specify operating system

Comment: I am talking about internet access. I am using UBUNTU LINUX

Comment: To what level shoudl you check the network? My PC connects to a LAN which connects to a WAN which connects to multiple gateways which all connect to the internet. The first level is 100 Mb. Would that 100 mb be the correct answer for you, regardless of the bandwidth limits imposed further on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for your network interface in /sys/class/net/ directory. My system only has two interfaces lo and eth0.

There are a lot of files describing the status of the interface to explore.

I would start with operstate, statistics/rx_bytes or statistics/rx_packets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two approaches - if you have a router with some sort of logging you could query it's values with SNMP or (harder) scrape the web interface for the stats.

Or if you need the real bandwidth you would have to find a server and download a file - measuring the time taken.